# How to modify IR auto-close circuit for trash can lid

Tags: hacking, photosensor

Just bought a new trash can with an automatic lid that I'm fairly happy with, but there's one modification I'd like to make.

If I place the trash can in a cabinet and close the door it detects the door in front of the IR sensor and holds the lid open indefinitely even though I would prefer it to be closed. You'd think it might eventually close the lid based on some kind of timer, but you'd be wrong.

[image: Controller Board Front]

[image: Controller Board Rear]

I have a few ideas for possible modification but I'm looking for any recommendations.

1. Change the microcontroller software to just close the lid after a set amount of time. This would be the simplest change if I were the manufacturer and could just add it to the microcontroller code and burn to the em78p372n ROM. Unfortunately in my case, I'm not the manufacturer so the workaround for me would be to use one of the dozen ESP32 or ESP8266 modules I've got lying around and create my own motion detector with a PIR sensor or something.
2. Add a photoresistor somewhere in the circuit for the IR detector so that it needs to detect an object AND have some amount of ambient light in order to truly trigger a detection. The cupboard closet will be pitch dark when closed. The difficulty here is that the controller board is a lot tighter than I'd hoped and it's not super obvious to me where the best place to splice in the photoresistor would be.
3. Maybe there's just something passive I could place on the closet door that would trick the sensor into thinking there isn't an object right on top of the sensor? The closet door basically touches the IR sensor window when closed so maybe a reflective tape or something to absorb the IR light would help?

Comment: Realistically you'll probably have to re-design most of the circuit, eg either learn how to re-program that MCU or more likely remove it and patch in one you are familiar with.   Questions on the usage/modification/repair of consumer products are off topic unless the question is stated in the context of a sufficiently thorough understanding of the subject circuit to be equivalent to the sort of specific *design* question which this site exists to support.  You probably know *approximately* how it works, but don't know *exactly* enough to know what to change without replacing most of it.

Comment: Consider just ripping everything upstream of the motor driver out and rigging up something to make the lid match the reading of a security-alarm type magnetic reed switch on the cabinet door.  Or as you mentioned a light sensor reacting to the *open* door.   Beware though if it is battery powered you have all the low power design challenges; you may need to power the light sensor only on a periodic polling basis a few times a second.

Comment: attach a piece of paper that is painted flat black on the cabinet door

Comment: Replace the IR LED-photo pair with a passive IR sensor. Or add a re-triggerable timer circuit in-line with the photo transistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just bought a sensor garbage can that I set on a cabinet drawer and it’s lid gets held open when I close the slide.

Got around it by taping a piece of aluminum foil onto a small cutting board, taped in the cabinet above the drawer at an angle.  If the IR gets reflected straight back by the foil it still activates the sensor but the angle bounces the IR away from the sensor.  Took a few tries to get the angle right but it’s working now.

Good luck with yours!

[image]